# Receiving "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick"

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, onclick

Errors...

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.vaidish.myapplication, PID: 12727
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6567)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6567) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:224)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:454)
    at com.example.vaidish.myapplication.Background.<init>(Background.java:25)
    at com.example.vaidish.myapplication.MainActivity.userLogin(MainActivity.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6567) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: We cannot help you without any code. If you want help, post code along with your question please.

Comment: [Too many duplicates to mention](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.lang.IllegalStateException%3A+Could+not+execute+method+for+android%3AonClick).

Comment: Yes I can post my code...but now I found my mistake....so its solved!! BTW Thank you for your suggestion & help.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your crash is this bit:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
>     at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:224)
>     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:454)
>     at com.example.vaidish.myapplication.Background.<init>(Background.java:25)
> ```

This says that you're passing `null` to the `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor. You could be doing that explicitly, like:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(null)
```

or you could be doing it unintentionally, like:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
```

Check line 25 of your `Background` class, and make sure you're passing a non-null `Context` instance to the builder.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion...I found my mistake & now my app work perfectly fine:)